# Calculating $\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right)}{x} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

How would you like to calculate this one? Do you see a fast, neat way here? Ideas?

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)\right)}{x} \, dx$$

*Sharing solutions is only optional*.

The closed form revealed is

$$\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{2 }{3}\log ^3(2)-\zeta(2) \log (2)+\zeta (3)\right).$$

Comment: What about integration by parts?

Comment: The artist always coming up with exceptional definite Integrals!

Comment: @OussamaBoussif what did i do ? :P

Comment: @The Artist haha what a coincidence. I actually meant the OP but it turns out that we have a true Artist among us :P

Comment: A trig subsitution and Beta function seem to solve the problem

Comment: @OussamaBoussif glad you like this stuff. ;)

Comment: @OussamaBoussif: I agree. This kind of integral is becoming a fashion topic (and quite a classical one) here on MSE :)

Comment: @OussamaBoussif yeah what a coincidence :P Or is it? :P

Comment: @The Artist Don't worry it is truely a coincidence :P. Just instead of saying the full name of the OP I said his last pseudo name

Comment: @OussamaBoussif  I know :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We want to compute:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(\sin\theta)\log\left(\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\cot(\theta)\,d\theta \tag{1}$$
and by integration by parts, the problem boils down to computing:
$$ J = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log^2(\sin\theta)\tan\frac{\theta}{2}\,d\theta =2\int_{0}^{1}\log^2\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}\right)\frac{t\,dt}{1+t^2}.\tag{2}$$
On the other hand, we have:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t\log^2(t)}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{3\zeta(3)}{16},\qquad \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t\log^2(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{\log^3(2)}{6},\tag{3}$$
where the first integral can be computed through differentiation under the integral sign, by exploiting the Euler beta function, while the second integral is elementary. In the same way we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{t\log(t)\log(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt = -\frac{\zeta(3)}{32} \tag{4}$$
so it is straightforward to compute $(2)$, then $(1)$.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. At first I tought of using Beta function but then I remembered it wasn't defined for $x,y=0$. But it seems that IBP works well in this case.

Comment: (+1) Maybe it's good to mention that this one is an elementary integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t\log^2(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{\log^3(2)}{2}-2\int_0^1 \frac{t \log ^2\left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2} \ dt \Rightarrow$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t\log^2(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt=\frac{\log^3(2)}{6}$$

and therefore no need for beta function, differentiations (that I don't know if they work). :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative solution.
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\frac{\ln{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)}{x}\ {\rm d}x
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^1_0\frac{\ln{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x}}{2}\right)}{x}\ {\rm d}x\tag1\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{2}\right)\ {\rm d}x\tag2\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\int^1_0\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{\sqrt{x}(1+\sqrt{x})}\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}\ {\rm d}x\tag3\\
&=-\frac{1}{96}\int^1_0x^{-3/2}\ln^3(1-x)\ {\rm d}x\tag4\\
&=\frac{1}{48}\lim_{q\to 1}\frac{\partial^3}{\partial q^3}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(q\right)}{\Gamma\left(q-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\tag5
\end{align}

---

Explanation:

$(1)$: Substituted $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$. 
$(2)$: Substituted $x\mapsto 1-x$. 
$(3)$: Integrated by parts. 
$(4)$: Integrated by parts. 
$(5)$: Used the integral representation of the Beta function.

---

Using Wolfram Alpha (or differentiating by hand),

[image]

Setting $q=1$ [gives us the required result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28d%5E3%2Fdq%5E3%29%281%2F48%29%28Gamma%281%2F2%29Gamma%28q%29%2FGamma%28q-1%2F2%29%29%20as%20q%20to%201).
$$\int^1_0\frac{\ln{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}\right)}{x}\ {\rm d}x=\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\ln{2}+\frac{\ln^3{2}}{6}$$